# Creating a zip file incrementally

Tags: linux, files, zip

I currently have a large directory on S3 (>100GB). I want to create a zip archive of this directory.

Currently, I download the contents of the directory and create a scratch (temp) directory on the server. I then use the `zip` utility to archive the scratch directory. What this means is that at its peak, I have 2 x directory size disk usage.

Instead of having a scratch directory, I was thinking of building the zip archive incrementally. This would halve disk usage since I only need to store the zip archive.

Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, are there any downsides I'm not seeing to this approach e.g. performance etc?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use tar and the --listed-incremental? If I understand well, you want to store the zipped files external? With --listed-incremental you need to keep on the server just the incremental file...

Comment: I have to use .zip- got some other constraints which means I can't use tar. After the zip file is created, I re-upload the zip to s3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Each time you issue `zip archive.zip file`, the `zip` will try to add the `file` into `archive.zip`. If archive does not exist it would be created, if exist - file would be added.

So, assuming you downloaded file to some temp folder:

```
$ zip -j big.zip /tmp/download/file.dat
```

Here, `-j` will "junk-path" the `/tmp/download/` path and `big.zip` will contain just `file.dat`

If you want to make an archive with paths, then you have to have a working directory `~/work`, so paths you want to see in archive are relative to that working directory. Then you download or create the file into `~/work/some/path/file.dat`. And do:

```
# first you need to be in the work directory, 
$ cd ~/work

# create (download) the file into relative path
$ mkdir -p some/path
$ touch some/path/file

# do the archiving
$ zip ~/big.zip some/path/file.dat

# remove the file and path to it
$ rm some/path/file.dat
$ rmdir -p some/path

# repeat for another file
```

Comment: Thanks. That's great. Would this have performance issues i.e. would it be slower than creating a temp directory first and then creating a zip?